# Link two ellipses by line WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I write number of ellipses to txtBox then by click add them on canvas.

I want to write number of ellipses which should be connected by line. But how to add coordinates of this line? I think it should be centres of ellipses but how to know its coordinates?

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="draw.ellipse"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="draw" Height="768" Width="1024" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Name="Create" Closed="Create_Closed">
<Canvas Name="can" Background="White" MouseDown="can_MouseDown">
    <TextBox Name="txbNumber" Height="34" Canvas.Left="797" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="5" Canvas.Top="76" Width="209" FontSize="18"/>
    <Button Name="btnCreate" Content="create" Canvas.Left="797" Canvas.Top="138" Width="209" Height="66" FontSize="18" Click="btnCreate_Click"/>
    <TextBox Name="txb1" Height="34" Canvas.Left="797" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="3" Canvas.Top="222" Width="78" FontSize="18"/>
    <Button Name="btnCreateEdge" Content="create edge" Canvas.Left="797" Canvas.Top="276" Width="209" Height="66" FontSize="18" Click="btnCreateEdge_Click"/>
    <TextBox Name="txb2" Height="34" Canvas.Left="928" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="4" Canvas.Top="222" Width="78" FontSize="18"/>
    <Label Name='lbl' Content="Label" Canvas.Left="797" Canvas.Top="374" Height="54" Width="169" FontSize="20"/>
</Canvas>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Graduate
{
/// <summary>
/// Логика взаимодействия для Create.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class draw: Window
{
    public draw()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int n, i, k, k2, j, j2, f;
    Ellipse[] v;
    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        n = Convert.ToInt16(txbNumber.Text);
        f = n;
        v = new Ellipse[n];
        var elipsy = can.Children.OfType<Ellipse>().ToList();
        foreach (var ellipses in elipsy)
        {
            can.Children.Remove(ellipses);
        }
    }


    private void Create_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
    private void can_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

        Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();
        SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        mySolidColorBrush.Color = Colors.Transparent;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            v[i] = new Ellipse();

            v[i].Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
            v[i].StrokeThickness = 2;
            v[i].Stroke = Brushes.Black;

            v[i].Width = 75;
            v[i].Height = 75;

            v[i].Margin = new Thickness(e.GetPosition(can).X, e.GetPosition(can).Y, 0, 0);



            can.Children.Add(v[i]);
        }
        if (n <= 0)
            return;
        n--;
    }

    private void btnCreateEdge_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        k2 = Convert.ToInt16(txb1.Text);
        j2 = Convert.ToInt16(txb2.Text);
        k = f - k2;
        j = f - j2;

        Line line = new Line();
        //line.X1 = v[k].;
        can.Children.Add(line);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: The center of the ellipse is simple it's X and Y coordinates plus half its width and height, respectively. What specifically are you having trouble with here? FWIW, it would be better to position your ellipses using the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties, than setting the margin as you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Your ellipses are positioned on top of each other when the handler is invoked, so even if you find a way to put a Line in them, you probably won't see it.

To answer your question:

1. Find the position of the ellipse via Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left. With these information together with its Width or Height, you can get the center of the ellipse.
2. You can use #1's information for your X1, X2 and Y1, Y2 of Line to connect ellipses.